# Troubles with: setConnection(Connection.AIRPLANE)

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I try to set AIRPLANE mode on Android emulator, but after execution I get:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: undefined status object (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

My code:

```
public static void enableAirplaneMode(){
        driver.setConnection(Connection.AIRPLANE);
        assertEquals(Connection.AIRPLANE, driver.getConnection());
        classLogger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection type is set: " + driver.getConnection());
    }
```

After step --> driver.setConnection(Connection.AIRPLANE); --> on emulator two modes are enabled, I see it on emulator settings(AIRPLANE and DATA) instead of AIRPLANE. And execution is failing:

```
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.CommandExecutionHelper.execute(CommandExecutionHelper.java:32)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.setConnection(AndroidDriver.java:230)
at core.screen_driver.ConfigureEmulatorOS.enableAirplaneMode(ConfigureEmulatorOS.java:33)
at step_definitions.GeneralDefs.enableAirplane(GeneralDefs.java:109)
```

Maybe anybody has a solving for this case?

Comment: Can you please add the version of your java-client and Appium server version?

Comment: java-client --- 4.1.2

Comment: Appium --- 1.4.16.1

Comment: Android version?

Comment: Android 5.1 lolipop

Answer (score 0):

Using `Connection.AIRPLANE` in

```
driver.setConnection(Connection.AIRPLANE);
```

Is only available from android Version 6.0 and above (For Emulators)

Please look at the appium docs for reference to `driver.setConnection()`

https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/en/writing-running-appium/network_connection/

I would also advise to update to the latest java-client and appium server.

Comment: Andrey, did it help?